# Fine-tune inception_v3 FailedPrecondition error for custom images dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, models

I am using tf (1.1.0 and 1.2.0) **models/slim/scripts** to finetune_inception_v3 for my 2 custom "logos" image datasets, previously converted to TFRecords

### Docker

all in Docker for windows with tensorflow container without GPU

```
docker run -it -v c:/tf_files:/tf_files gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0-devel (also 1.2.0-devel)
```

### TFRecords

```
bazel-bin/inception/build_image_data \
  --train_directory="${TRAIN_DIR}" \
  --validation_directory="${VALIDATION_DIR}" \
  --output_directory="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}" \
  --labels_file="${LABELS_FILE}" \
  --train_shards=2 \
  --validation_shards=2 \
  --num_threads=2
```

with LABELS_FILE=/tmp/data/labels.txt   for 2 image categories

```
ProperLogos
OtherLogos
```

### Models Slim cloned

```
/slimtf# git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

added *logos.py* to datasets directory and updated *dataset_factory.py* to support "logos" custom dataset
changed *datatset_utils.py* where changed LABELS_FILENAME = 'labels2.txt'
because it expected "**labels_id colon names**" format there as I found in the code

```
0:ProperLogos
1:OtherLogos
```

### Fine-tune

```
/slimtf/models/slim# ./scripts/finetune_inception_v3_on_logos.sh
```

starts 1st cmd train_image_classifier.py 
Fine-tuning from /tmp/checkpoints/inception_v3.ckpt

```
# Fine-tune only the new layers for 1000 steps.
python train_image_classifier.py \
  --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --dataset_name=logos \
  --dataset_split_name=train \
  --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
  --model_name=inception_v3 \
  --checkpoint_path=${PRETRAINED_CHECKPOINT_DIR}/inception_v3.ckpt \
  --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits \
  --trainable_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits \
  --max_number_of_steps=1000 \
  --batch_size=12 \
  --learning_rate=0.01 \
  --learning_rate_decay_type=fixed \
  --save_interval_secs=60 \
  --save_summaries_secs=60 \
  --log_every_n_steps=100 \
  --clone_on_cpu=True \
  --optimizer=rmsprop \
  --weight_decay=0.00004
```

it fails on FailedPreconditionError: /tmp/logos/train

```
 /slimtf/models/slim# ./scripts/finetune_inception_v3_on_logos.sh

INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Ignoring --checkpoint_path because a checkpoint already exists in /tmp/models-logos4a/inception_v3
2017-07-02 02:11:51.859377: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-02 02:11:51.859402: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-02 02:11:51.859408: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-02 02:11:51.859413: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-02 02:11:51.859418: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/models-logos4a/inception_v3/model.ckpt-0
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path /tmp/models-logos4a/inception_v3/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError'>, /tmp/logos/train
         [[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2_1 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2_1, parallel_read/filenames)]]
2017-07-02 02:11:55.725083: W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:303] _6_prefetch_queue/fifo_queue: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_image_classifier.py", line 573, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train_image_classifier.py", line 569, in main
    sync_optimizer=optimizer if FLAGS.sync_replicas else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 767, in train
    sv.stop(threads, close_summary_writer=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 792, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1193, in _single_operation_run
    target_list_as_strings, status, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: /tmp/logos/train
         [[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2_1 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2_1, parallel_read/filenames)]]
```

is there anything missing in my input directories for train and validation? 
*/tmp/logos/train*

```
train-00000-of-00002  train-00001-of-00002
```

*/tmp/logos/validation*

```
validation-00000-of-00002  validation-00001-of-00002
```

Comment: Could you specify which edits did you do to dataset_utils.py? Also, it would be very helpful to have a look at logos.py as I suspected the error is in there..

Comment: @GPhilo you were right, logos.py and actually the </br> _#_FILE_PATTERN = 'logos_%s_*.tfrecord'_
 for TFRecords was the issue. Found that after some experimentes with input data  paths. Thx

Comment: please mark as resolved :)

Comment: I had the same problem, that's why I thought it could be in there. Can't mark anything as resolved, you're the one who made the question. I suggest you write a short answer to the question and mark that one as resolving the question

Comment: right @GPhilo that was ment to someone who can :o)

Comment: that's the thing, you can ;)